# How can we make Google display our website like Twitter and other big sites?

Tags: search-engine, google-search

If you search for Twitter on Google, you will see the following:

[image: Twitter in a Google search]

How can I make our website show up as this (with section sub-headers) in the Google search results?

Comment: +1 for original title including "the google", even though it's since been edited to favor correctness over style

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO and is asked every other day

Answer (score 1):

i came to know that google does it at its own when required. We can use the webmasters tool to remove the sitelinks when the search is done.

Answer (score 0):

See Google's article on site links

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

This can be done on the [Google Webmaster Tools page](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en) as described in [Google's Sitelinks article.](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en)

> #### Demote a sitelink URL:
>
> 1. On the Webmaster Tools Home page, click the site you want.
> 2. Under **Search Appearance**, click **Sitelinks**.
> 3. In the **For this search result** box, complete the URL for which you don't want a specific sitelink URL to appear. ([How to find the right URL.](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/answer.py?answer=63758))
> 4. In the **Demote this sitelink URL** box, complete the URL of the sitelink you want to demote.